# Netty and GUI for Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netty

I created a simple Netty Application with a server and client to interact through the console. Now I am trying to add a GUI so the client can view/and enter their messages w/o the console.

I decided it would not be wise to create the GUI in the same class that is used to create the channel.

Here is an example of my Main Client Class.

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
            .group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChatClientInitializer());

        Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while (true) {
            channel.writeAndFlush((in.readLine() + "\r\n"));
        }

    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

How do I create the GUI so that when the user enters a message in the JTextField it will be passed to the `channel.writeAndFlush` method?

Do I create an instance of the GUI in the .run method.

Also the second part of my question, in my handler class (code below) how do I pass an incoming message to the `JTextArea` in my GUI?

Here is a sample of the the very basic Handler Class right now.

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(msg);

}
```

And for reference here is my GUI class.

```
public ClientGUI(){ 
    enterField = new JTextField();
    enterField.setEditable(true);
    enterField.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                    enterField.setText("");
                }
            });
    add(enterField,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    displayArea = new JTextArea();
    add (new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(300,150);
    setVisible(true);   
}

public void sendMessage(String message){
//      what to do here?        
}
```

Comment: The GUI should operate within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, your message dispatcher should (or could) operate within in its own Thread.  The GUI will need a reference to dispatcher and the dispatcher will need some kind of method where by the GUI and tell it what to send.  The dispatcher could use some kind of queue, for example, popping each message of the queue and sending. While the queue is empty, it could idle (or `sleep`) until there is something to be sent

Comment: Sorry MadProgrammer thanks for the help, but you have me a little lost. What would be my Event Dispatching Thead?

Comment: The EDT is the main GUI thread. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Ok I spent some time reading up. The article confirmed what you said is that Swing GUI should operate out of the Event Dispatching Thread. It seems like most of my Swing Events will be running out out this thread because with a simple chat GUI it is all short tasks. My question is now can I take this knowledge and use it for my program. I have a GUI class where should it be initialized so that is is running in it's own thread? What is the best way to get the GUI class to use the channel, and Handler I already have created?

Comment: As I said, you dispatcher class should run in its own thread. It will need a method that can be called which tells it when to send a message. You would have reference to the dispatcher in the GUI and would call this "send message" method when ever you want to send a message

Answer (score 1):

`ClientGUI` class must have a reference to the `Channel` to communicate via.  Assuming that you also have a reference to the `ClientGUI` instance somewhere and the `Channel` is created after GUI is initialized, you could add some setter to `ClientGUI`:

```
public class ClientGUI {
    private volatile Channel channel;

    public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public void sentMessage(String msg) {
        channel.writeAndFlush(msg);
    }
    ...
}
```