# Swing client rests on Netty for I/O -- how do I send/receive from the GUI?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, netty

For right now, the client instantiates the Swing GUI.  This seems to work, to a degree.

What's the correct flow to allow messages to get passed to, and received from, the GUI?

In the GUI, which extends JFrame for convenience:

```
private void nextTitleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_nextTitleActionPerformed
    title = new Title();
}//GEN-LAST:event_nextTitleActionPerformed
```

how do I pass that title through netty, that is, to the `ClientHandler`, so that this object is sent from the client to the server?

I toyed with starting the `Client` and `ClientHandler` from within the GUI directly, but there's no real "instance" of `ClientHandler` to invoke method calls on.

Perhaps there's a Netty helper or interface which the Swing GUI can pass methods through?  I've read a bit of a [book on netty](http://www.manning.com/maurer/), but that book doesn't seem to address this topic.  (Hmm, I'll take another look at the appendix, it has some demo's.)

client code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client.netty;

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ClassResolvers;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectEncoder;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.TitlesGUI;

public final class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());
    private final TitlesGUI gui = new TitlesGUI();

    public Client() {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, SSLException {
        MyProps p = new MyProps();
        String host = p.getHost();
        int port = p.getServerPort();
        new Client().startClient(host, port);
    }

    public void startClient(final String host, final int port) throws SSLException, InterruptedException {
        gui.setVisible(true);
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast(
                                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                                    new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                                    new ClientHandler());
                        }
                    });
            b.connect(host, port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

handler code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client.netty;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.jdbc.Title;

public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Title> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName());

    public ClientHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptInboundMessage(Object msg) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        log.info(msg.toString());
        ctx.write(new Title());
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext chc, Title title) throws Exception {
        log.info(title.toString());
        chc.write(new Title());
    }
}
```

server output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
Jul 26, 2014 8:10:24 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRegistered
INFO: [id: 0x15d5077e] REGISTERED
Jul 26, 2014 8:10:24 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler bind
INFO: [id: 0x15d5077e] BIND(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:4454)
Jul 26, 2014 8:10:24 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelActive
INFO: [id: 0x15d5077e, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:4454] ACTIVE
Jul 26, 2014 8:13:31 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler logMessage
INFO: [id: 0x15d5077e, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:4454] RECEIVED: [id: 0xbcbabb1e, /127.0.0.1:34604 => /127.0.0.1:4454]
^Cthufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/AgentServer$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/AgentServer$
```

The server seems to acknowledge a connection from the client (and can send and receive with a headless version).

The question is:

how do I send objects to the GUI, or get objects from the GUI?  The `TitlesGUI` class extends `JFrame`.

Comment: Where's your GUI code? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  The GUI is a bit long to include(?).  It's just a JFrame with some buttons.  When a button is clicked, then...   the problem is that the GUI doesn't have a reference to the **handler**, nor does the **handler** have a reference to the GUI.  I'll add some code, just event listener for a button -- standard Swing.  But, it doesn't connect to anything netty related.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849779/netty-and-gui-for-java

Comment: @Thufir I know it was a while ago but how did you workaround this? same issue here with the netty handler and gui.